# Whether this integration is finite under the given condition?

Tags: calculus

$a>b>\frac{d-1}{p}-1/2$ and $1\leq p<\infty$. Then whether the following integration is finite?

$$\int_0^\pi sin(x)^{d-2}(\frac{1}{x})^{(a+1/2)p} (\frac{1}{\pi-x})^{(b+1/2)p}dx $$

I divide this integration into $[0,\pi/2]$ and $[\pi/2, \pi]$ and used $sinx\leq x$, but found this can not prove it is integrable. So I am wondering if there are some other ways to prove this integration is finite.

This is a step of my reading materials which says a step is obviously. I try to prove the obvious step by converting that integration into this form. If it is finite, then my way to prove that step is true. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Near $x = 0$, and up to a constant, the integrand can be approximated as

$$x^{d - 2} \cdot \left(\frac 1 x\right)^{(a + 1/2)p}$$

using the fact that $\sin x \approx x$ (more particularly, that $\frac 1 2 x \le \sin x \le x$ for $x$ sufficiently close to zero) and that the third term is essentially constant there. Overall, this portion will converge provided that

$$d - 2 - (a + 1/2)p > -1$$

or equivalently

$$d - (a + 1/2)p > 1$$

or even better, if

$$a < \frac{d - 1}{p} - \frac 1 2.$$

Now compare this to your original condition about $a$. As a similar exercise, you may wish to do the same analysis at the other endpoint.

Comment: Thanks very much. Then my way to attach the obvious step of that material is wrong. Thanks a lot